# What's the meaning of "structure" here?

Tags: meaning

How do you define structure in this context? I'm unsure which definition is appropriate from the dictionary.

> P1: Healthy, fit people that can't die are like poison to big pharma. The new technology won't replace the lost profit from slinging drugs by a longshot.
>
> P2: How can you possibly say this without having the slightest clue of the potential demand and cost structure of this treatment?

Comment: The thing you might want to search for is "cost structure"

Comment: silly me, I read it as demand and cost structure.

Comment: @tchrist: That's a better reason for an edit than for a downvote.

Comment: @ruakh You’re right.  The thinking was that if I had just edited it, he wouldn’t have noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, here the whole expression "cost structure" should be defined, not only the word "structure" itself. And "cost structure" is something like the expenses that a firm is supposed to take into account while manufacturing a product.